# Wordpress : How to programmatically GET (to know) which Sidebar (or) which Menu is being used on Different Pages?

Tags: wordpress, function, menu, sidebar

Lets say i want to detect such thing from the "functions.php" .. to know which `Sidebar` (or) which `Menu` is being loaded on current (whatever landed) page, how can i know?

Lets say i have a few pages, with:

- Page A (with Sidebar: "Today Weather" / Menu: "Apples")
- Page B (with Sidebar: "To-do List" / Menu: "Oranges")
- Page C (with Sidebar: "To-do List" / Menu: "Apples")
- Page D (with Sidebar: "Today Weather" / Menu: "Oranges")

From `functions.php`, if:

- there's the `Sidebar`: "To-do List" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition A";`.
- there's the `Sidebar`: "Today Weathers" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition B";`.
- there's the `Menu`: "Apples" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition C";`.
- there's the `Menu`: "Oranges" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition D";`.

So the thing here is:

- **How to KNOW the IDs of the things currently loaded.**

How to simply do it please.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook action and filter for specific functions.

```
add_action( 'get_sidebar', 'get_sidebar_name' );
function get_sidebar_name($name) {
    var_dump($name);
}
```

Variable $name will contain name for sidebar. If empty then it will be default sidebar.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'random_wp_nav_menu_args' );
function random_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    print_r($args);
    return $args;
}
```

$args variable contains almost the same data you pass to function. You can see theme_locationa and menu name. For wp_nav_menu there are other filter you can hook into.

You can see action call in [get_sidebar function source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L102)

And in [wp_nav_menu function source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L224)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$pageid = get_the_ID(); //to get page id

if( $pageid == 12 ) //here 12 apples page id
{
  echo "Condition C";
}
if( $pageid == 13 ) //here 13 orange page id
{
  echo "Condition C";

//for sidebar

if( dynamic_sidebar('To-do List')) 
{
 echo "Condition A";
}
if( dynamic_sidebar('Today Weather')) 
{
 echo "Condition B";
}
or,

<?php 
foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) { 

         echo $sidebar['id']; 
         echo $sidebar['name'];

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to get sidebar name nor menu name.